# PHP webdriver selecting an option leaves the other option selected

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

When clicking an option in the select dropdown it leaves the other option selected.

**HTML**

```
<select name="Fm112_Ctrl3227_LB" id="Fm112_Ctrl3227_LB" size="5" multiple="multiple" style="background-color:#d3e2f9;width:100px;" title="To select one or more items from the list, hold down the Ctrl key.">
    <option value="721" title="Active" selected="selected">Active</option>
    <option value="722" title="Expired">Expired</option>
    <option value="727" title="Sold">Sold</option>
    <option value="723" title="Off market">Off market</option>
    <option value="719" title="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
    </select>
```

Selecting one option does not unselect the original one.

I tried selecting the element in multiple ways including looking up the element value with xpath and sending a click as well as WebDriverSelect, but it didn't help.

Is there anything else I can try?

This is the code I tried

```
$dropdown = new WebDriverSelect($driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('Fm112_Ctrl3227_LB')));
$dropdown->selectByValue('727');
```

And

```
$allOptions = $dropdown->findElements(WebDriverBy::tagName('option'));
foreach ($allOptions as $option) {

    if($option->getAttribute('value') == "727") {
        $option->click();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following monstrosity worked. It looks like you have to combine WebDriverSelect::selectByValue with a clickAndHold otherwise it won't work.

**WebDriverSelect::selectByValue**

```
// Look for the select dropdown with ID Fm112_Ctrl3227_LB and select the option with the value 727

$dropdown = new WebDriverSelect($driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('Fm112_Ctrl3227_LB')));
$dropdown->selectByValue('727');
```

**clickAndHold**

```
// Look for the select dropdown with ID Fm112_Ctrl3227_LB and click and hold the option with the value 727
$dropdown   = $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('Fm112_Ctrl3227_LB'));
$allOptions = $dropdown->findElements(WebDriverBy::tagName('option'));

foreach ($allOptions as $option) {

    if($option->getAttribute('value') == "727") {

        $driver->action()
            ->moveToElement($option)
            ->clickAndHold($option)
            ->perform();

    }

}
```